# How to prevent a movable character going off the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have an object that I am able to move around using the arrow keys on the keyboard, however, the object moves off the screen. How can I get the object to remain on the screen?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
            case 37:
                $('img').animate({left: "-=30px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 38:
                $('img').animate({top: '-=30px'},'fast');
                break;
            case 39:
                $('img').animate({left: '+=30px'},'fast');
                break;
            case 40:
                $('img').animate({top: '+=30px'},'fast');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Code has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugeshgupta000/a5sccbxq/)

I have removed the animation, because during animation, position().left will give e the same old value and `left` position value is updated only after animation. So in that case, picture can move out of the window despite the code being present. If you require to use animation, you should think of some timeout function.

Comment: Thank you so much!